# How do I convert this Applescript to Terminal osascript?

Tags: terminal, applescript

I'm trying to convert this AppleScript into osascript format that can be run from terminal:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to activate
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "input" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    repeat until exists tab group 1 of window "Sound"
    end repeat
    tell table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
        select (row 1 where value of text field 1 is "Internal Microphone")
    end tell
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

What is the appropriate syntax to do this? Do I have to type `osascript -e` before every line?

Comment: There’s no such thing as “osascript format.”  The *command* `osascript` is what you use to run AppleScript commands or scripts from the command line.  See [`man osascript`](https://ss64.com/osx/osascript.html) for details on how to use the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish the goal. Here is the method I would use...

In **Terminal** run the following *compound command*, e.g.:

```
f="myscript"; touch "$f"; open -e "$f"; chmod +x "$f"
```

- Note: Change `myscript` to the name you'd like.

In the new blank **TextEdit** document that opens, add the following as the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
```

Then add your **AppleScript** *code* under the *shebang* you just added.

Save the document.

Now to use it in **Terminal**, e.g.:

```
./myscript
```

Or:

```
/path/to/myscript
```

Or place in in a *directory* that is within the defined `PATH` and then simply use its *name*, e.g.:

```
myscript
```

---

This method also works; however it's not practical for long *scripts*:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Preferences" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Preferences"' -e 'reveal anchor "input" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"' -e 'end tell' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"' -e 'repeat until exists tab group 1 of window "Sound"' -e 'end repeat' -e 'tell table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window 1' -e 'select (row 1 where value of text field 1 is "Internal Microphone")' -e 'end tell' -e 'end tell' -e 'quit application "System Preferences"'
```

Please read the *manual page* for `osascript` for additional information. In **Terminal**:

```
man osascript
```

---

On a separate note, if you omit the following line of *code* you'll not have to see the **System Preferences** *window* flash on the screen:

Saved as as *script*, remove:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to activate
```

In the very long drawn out *command line*, remove:

```
-e 'tell application "System Preferences" to activate'
```

Answer (score -3):

yes you have to put `osascript -e` before every line like this:

```
osascript -e 'display dialog "Hello from osxdaily.com" with title "Hello"'
```

and I hope [this link](https://osxdaily.com/2016/08/19/run-applescript-command-line-macos-osascript/) will help you more.

Comment: How does "put .. before each line" work for the script shown in the question? Also I'm not so sure how the linked page helps in this.