# Is it possible to convert an apple script w/ Idle to Shell Script?

Tags: applescript, command-line, bash

The Apple Script repeats every minute when saved as an application and the box is checked as "stay open after run handler". I used this method to convert it to Shell Script: [How do I convert this Applescript to Terminal osascript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389637/how-do-i-convert-this-applescript-to-terminal-osascript) , but it won't repeat as it does in the Apple Script. However it will work without the idle commands, but of course, it doesn't repeat. How do I get it to work? Is there a better syntax to use to have it repeat than #idle, #return 60 #end idle?

Apple Script

```
on idle
    tell application "Finder"
        if not (disk "Backup_Server" exists) then
            display alert "Backup_Server not found, please mount"
        end if
        delay 5
        if not (disk "Backup_Server" exists) then
            display alert "Backup_Server still not found, please submit a ticket"
            return 60
        end if
    end tell
end idle
on quit
    continue quit
end quit
```

Shell Script

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
on idle
    tell application "Finder"
        if not (disk "Backup_Server" exists) then
            display alert "Backup_Server not found, please mount"
        end if
        delay 5
        if not (disk "Backup_Server" exists) then
            display alert "Backup_Server still not found, please submit a ticket"
            return 60
        end if
    end tell
end idle
on quit
    continue quit
end quit
```

Comment: You shouldn’t really be polling for the presence of a disk and definitely not with _Finder_ (use _System Events_ or, better yet, use the shell to test for it if polling is too irresistible).  Instead, you can set up a monitor for the folder "/Volumes" folder to execute a script when the backup disk is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an **AppleScript** *script* saved as a *shell script* you cannot use `on idle`, and `return 60` unless you want `return 60` to *return* `60`

Use a `repeat` *loop* instead of an `on idle` *handler*, and replace `return` with `delay`.

The `on quit` *handler* is only good if you issued a `quit` *command* elsewhere in the *code*, otherwise you'd need to use **⌃C** to *quit* the **AppleScript** *shell script* to break out of the `repeat` *loop*, unless you have *coded* a way out of it.